# Why is this function not giving consistent output?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I am making a tic-tac-toe AI just for fun. I made a successors function that returns a dictionary with the start state as the key, and all of the states that come immediately after as the value.

The function is working fine as far as I can tell(all though I still need to remove the symmetric states), but for some reason every time I run the function, the tuple of successors states is in a different order. I get the same values, but they are scrambled.

```
from itertools import *

def successors(state):
    vars = [0]*state.count(0)
    vars[0] = 'x'
    vars[1] = 'o'
    vars = list(set(permutations(vars)))
    state = tuple([state[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(state), 3)])
    states = []
    for var in vars:
        new_board = []
        for row in state:
            new_row = []
            for tile in row:
                if tile != 0:
                    new_row.append(tile)
                else:
                    new_row.append(var[0])
                    var = var[1:]
            new_board.append(tuple(new_row))
        states.append(tuple(new_board))
    return {state:states}


board = (0,0,0,
         0,0,0,
         0,0,0)

print(successors(board))
```

Is there a variable somewhere that isn't getting reset?

Comment: Every time you run the function?  Or every time you run the program?  I'm betting it's the latter -- and I'm guessing you're running python2.7 with hash randomization enabled.

Comment: @mgilson: Why 2.7? [3.4 has SipHash enabled by default](https://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-pep-456).

Comment: @user2357112 -- Some reason I was thinking that it started being enabled by default at python2.7 and 3.3 (respectively).  had I noticed that OP uses `print` as a function, I wouldn't have been that specific :-/

Comment: [3.3 has randomization enabled by default too, though not as good](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html). (I wasn't sure when that change went in. It took me a bit longer to look it up.) As far as I know, no 2.x version has it on by default.

Comment: A `set` is unordered, so when you say `list(set(permutations(vars)))` you essentially throw every assumption of orderness out of the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because you do:

```
vars = list(set(permutations(vars)))
```

The order here is arbitrary and can be different from one run to the next due to hash randomization.  To disable it, you set the [`PYTHONHASHSEED`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED) environment variable to a constant value -- e.g. `0`